# R: Create set of columns that correspond to binary output of another set of columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset where there are a set of columns where values can either be 1 or 0. I would like to create a new set of columns (`path_1`:`path_n`) that indicates the column headers that had a 1.

Here is a snippet of my dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3),
                 `1_0_1_0` = c(1, 0, 0), `1_0_0_0` = c(0, 0, 1),
                 `2_0_1_0` = c(1, 1, 0), `2_0_3_0` = c(0, 0, 0),
                 check.names = FALSE)
```

My expected output would be like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### (1) `base` solution

```
ind <- 2:5
path.seq <- seq_len(max(rowSums(df[ind])))
mat <- apply(df[ind] > 0, 1, \(x) names(which(x))[path.seq])
row.names(mat) <- paste0("path", path.seq)
cbind(df, t(mat))

#   ID 1_0_1_0 1_0_0_0 2_0_1_0 2_0_3_0   path1   path2
# 1  1       1       0       1       0 1_0_1_0 2_0_1_0
# 2  2       0       0       1       0 2_0_1_0    <NA>
# 3  3       0       1       0       0 1_0_0_0    <NA>
```

> **Update:** Replace the `mat` line as follows to deal with the situation where columns can take any non-negative integers.
>
> ```r
> mat <- apply(df[ind], 1, \(x) rep(names(df)[ind], x)[path.seq])
> ```

---

##### (2) `tidyverse` solution

###### Option 1

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>%
  filter(value > 0) %>%
  # uncount(value) %>%
  mutate(path = paste0("path", row_number()), .by = ID) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, names_from = path, values_from = name) %>%
  left_join(df, ., by = "ID")
```

> **Update:** Insert `uncount(value)` between `filter()` and `mutate()` to deal with the situation where columns can take any non-negative integers.

###### Option 2

```r
df %>%
  mutate(
    across(-ID, ~ if_else(.x > 0, cur_column(), NA)) %>%
      unite("path", sep = ';', na.rm = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  separate_wider_delim(path, delim = ';', names_sep = '', too_few = "align_start")

# # A tibble: 3 × 7
#      ID `1_0_1_0` `1_0_0_0` `2_0_1_0` `2_0_3_0` path1   path2  
#   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  
# 1     1         1         0         1         0 1_0_1_0 2_0_1_0
# 2     2         0         0         1         0 2_0_1_0 NA     
# 3     3         0         1         0         0 1_0_0_0 NA
```

Comment: In my dataset, I also have a lot of other columns besides ID. How would I adjust for that?

Comment: @ltong You can input the indices of target columns as a vector into `pivot_longer()`. In this example, `pivot_longer(-ID)` is equal to `pivot_longer(2:5)`.

Comment: I unfortunately made a change to my data, where the columns can take beyond binary values (also 2, 3). For those values, is there a way to break out the multiples? For example, if [1,2] = 2 instead, then path1 = 1_0_1_0, path2 = 1_0_1_0, path 3 = 2_0_1_0.

Comment: @ltong See my update to the `base` solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3), `1_0_1_0` = c(1, 0, 0), `1_0_0_0` = c(0, 
                                                                  0, 1), `2_0_1_0` = c(1, 1, 0), `2_0_3_0` = c(0, 0, 0))

df$path1 = NA
df$path2 = NA

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  cols_with_1 <- names(df[i, -1])[df[i, -1] == 1]
  if (length(cols_with_1) >= 1) {
    df$path1[i] <- cols_with_1[1]
  }
  if (length(cols_with_1) >= 2) {
    df$path2[i] <- cols_with_1[2]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, please try the below code

```r
nam <- apply(df[-1],1, \(x) names(which(x==1)) )

df2 <- do.call(rbind, nam) %>% as.data.frame() %>% setNames(c('path1','path2'))

df2$match <- apply(df2, 1, \(x) all(x[1]==x))
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(across(c(path2), ~ ifelse(match==T, NA, .x)))
df3 <- cbind(df,df2)
```

```r
  ID 1_0_1_0 1_0_0_0 2_0_1_0 2_0_3_0   path1   path2 match
1  1       1       0       1       0 1_0_1_0 2_0_1_0 FALSE
2  2       0       0       1       0 2_0_1_0    <NA>  TRUE
3  3       0       1       0       0 1_0_0_0    <NA>  TRUE
```

Comment: Some comments: (1) Your code cannot deal with row where all values are zeros. E.g. ``df$`1_0_0_0`[3] <- 0`` (2) `setNames(c('path1','path2'))` is a typical case of hard-coding. How could you know the max path is 2? You should generate the paths automatically instead of by your eyes. (4) It seems that you have used external packages. You should specify it.